# aggregate select fields of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

with `table1` like below

```
+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+---------+
|          time           |  regno |  radar |  speed |  heading |  people |  lights |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+---------+
| 2017/03/28 06:00:06.112 |     11 |   1100 |     50 |  down    |       4 |  false  |
| 2017/03/28 06:00:06.112 |     12 |   1111 |     40 |  up      |       1 |  false  |
| 2017/03/28 06:00:06.113 |     11 |   1100 |     50 |  down    |       4 |  false  |
| 2017/03/28 06:00:07.100 |     21 |   1100 |     60 |  down    |       4 |  false  |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+---------+
```

I need to generate an output table where the aggregate values of select fields from `table1` is captured like below.

```
+-----------+-------+------+------+---------+
| attribute |  avg  |  min |  max |  median |
+-----------+-------+------+------+---------+
| speed     |    50 |   40 |   60 |      40 |
| people    |  3.25 |    1 |    4 |       4 |
+-----------+-------+------+------+---------+
```

I could do aggregate each attribute separately in temp tables and then do a union of the temp tables to get the above output, but it becomes unwieldy when there are a large number of attributes which in my case is around 20 - are there smarter ways of going about this?

Comment: You can write a function.  You can find column name of table using  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table. After finding all columns write a function which creates query for each column and union it. In this way you do need to worry about your number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by union query, try this

```
SELECT avg(speed),min(speed),max(speed),'speed' as speed FROM `table1`
UNION 
SELECT avg(people),min(people),max(people),'people' as people FROM `table1`
```

Comment: This is almost identical to the answer already given by @dev8080 and it also omits the median.